# Thymeleaf Cannot execute subtraction:

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-el

i want to add an th:text in select option (Thymeleaf),

```
<option th:each="case : ${caseCategoryList}" th:value="${case.caseCategoryId}" th:text="${case.caseCategoryName} - ${case.caseCategoryCode}"></option>
```

but i get this error

```
08:28:05,501 ERROR [[servlet-context]] Servlet.service() for servlet servlet-context threw exception
        org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Cannot execute subtraction: operands are "INPATIENT" and "IP" (memberrki/member-rki-form:124)
            at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SubtractionExpression.executeSubtraction(SubtractionExpression.java:91)
            at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.ComplexExpression.executeComplex(ComplexExpression.java:58)
            at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:107)
            at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:133)
            at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:120)
            at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.attr.AbstractStandardTextChildModifierAttrProcessor.getText(AbstractStandardTextChildModifierAttrProcessor.java:68)
            at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractTextChildModifierAttrProcessor.getModifiedChildren(AbstractTextChildModifierAttrProcessor.java:59)
            at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractChildrenModifierAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractChildrenModifierAttrProcessor.java:58)
            at org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87)
            at org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212)
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1016)
            at org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:971)
             ...
```

can you help me to fix this error,

Comment: The operator 'SUBTRACT' is not supported between objects of type String and String

Answer (score 2):

Using `&#45` as suggested by glytching didn't work for me. However, this worked:

```
th:text="${case.caseCategoryName} + '-' + ${case.caseCategoryCode}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf is interpreting this: `th:text="${case.caseCategoryName} - ${case.caseCategoryCode}"` as *subtract the value of caseCategoryCode from caseCategoryName as display the result*.

And, since these are String values, the subtraction fails.

I suspect you don't want to subtract them at all and instead you want to display the two vaues separated by a hyphen. Like this:

```
INPATIENT - IP
```

To do that you can escape the hyphen so that Thymeleaf does not treat it as a subtraction operator:

```
th:text="${case.caseCategoryName} &#45; ${case.caseCategoryCode}"
```